# How do I implement tinymce.Shortcuts in TinyMCE v4

Tags: tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts, tinymce-4

I want to add keyboard shortcuts to my TinyMCE editor.

Here is my init code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    mode : "exact",
    plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
    'print'
    ],
    toolbar: 'print | styleselect | bullist numlist',
});
```

I know that I need something along the lines of:

```
editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', function() {});
```

But I don't understand how to connect the shortcuts code with my init code.

TinyMCE documentation [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.shortcuts/), but I was having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expansion of the answer @Thariama provided.  Code that worked for me was:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    mode : "exact",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', desc, function() { //desc can be any string, it is just for you to describe your code.
            // your code here
        });
    },
    plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
    'print'
    ],
    toolbar: 'print | styleselect | bullist numlist',
});
```

Alternatively you can also use the following, which will allow you to override key commands reserved by TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    mode : "exact",
    setup: function(e) {
      e.on("keyup", function(e) {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {  // keyCode 27 is for the ESC key, just an example, use any key code you like
          // your code here
        }
      });
    },
    plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
    'print',
    ],
    toolbar: 'print | styleselect | bullist numlist',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML

  // add your shortcuts here
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', function() {});
  }
});
```

Use the [setup](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) init parameter!

Comment: Question about this answer.  In order for this to work for me, I also have to add a string describing the function.  So not working:
`editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', function() {});`  Working: 

`editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+a', myCommandDescription, function() {});`  I came to this conclusion after trying deprecated code I found in the TinyMCE archived documentation [here](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addShortcut).  Are you able to get a key command to work without adding in that description string?

Comment: no, because the add function is a tinymce core function, but you can use an empty string

Comment: Thanks for your help @Thariama.  You got me going in the right direction.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the two previous answers, here is a full example:

```
tinymce.init({
//here you can have selector, menubar...
setup: function (editor) {
       setLocale(editor);
            // For the keycode (eg. 13 = enter) use: cf http://keycode.info 
            editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+13', 'indent', function(){      
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('indent');
            });

            editor.shortcuts.add('ctrl+f', 'subscript ', function(){      
                tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('subscript');
            });
        },
        });
```